# Writing a dataframe in Parquet

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, parquet

I am trying to read a json in spark and write it back as parquet. I am running my code in windows. Below is my code. After the execution it creates a folder called output_spark.parquet. And it also throws an error that the file is not found. If i create a file and then run the code it says that the file already exists. Here is the error i get.

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> o34.parquet. : java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset

Do i need file writer to write the parquet to the file? Appreciate any code snippets you might have.

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.json("Output.json")

df.show()

 
df.write.parquet("output_spark.parquet")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, Hadoop requires native code extensions so that it can integrate with the OS correctly for things like file access semantics and permissions.   HOW TO FIX THIS ?

1. get the WINUTILS.EXE binary from a Hadoop redistribution. use this  [link](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/winutils.exe)
2. Set the environment variable %HADOOP_HOME% to point to the directory above the BIN dir containing WINUTILS.EXE: well search for "EDIT USER VARIABLE" in the search bar in windows and then set it [image: user variable]

Comment: no don't worry , we are here to share knowldge no one starts expert , well not an obligation you need to have the folder where spark has to point on.

Comment: Sorry for removing my follow up question, I was able to find the answer for the winutils... thank you, will try it out now.

Comment: for your second question try to use this : df.write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').save("output_spark.parquet") you will not have the problem (file already exists)

Comment: Thank you, The process created a directory called output_spark.parquet. Below is the error i am getting .............................................................................  21/03/03 18:36:19 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job cc2b4552-dd54-494a-b262-7ee90ab8d85a.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z                               ......

Comment: download the hadoop.dll and add it to the same folder where the winutils.exe is , here is a link https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/hadoop.dll

Comment: I get the same error. Do i need to install spark also ? It might look obvious that i need to install, but, if i need spark to be installed wouldn't it have failed to create the spark session in the first place?. But, let me know if Spark needs to be installed for winutils etc to work.

Comment: Well  executing pip install pyspark installs already Spark. Well I will share a link and choose the Hadoop.dll and winutils.exe of the same Hadoop version ( for example 2.7 or wherever you like ) here is the github link

Comment: can you add the link please? I think you forgot

Comment: sorry just i need to mention that you need to restart your machine after setting the env

Comment: Okay, I have added the winutils to the windows path too and did the trick. @Belghith thank you for taking time to answer the question, appreciate your help.