# PySpark shell command produces no output

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

While reinstalling Spark binaries on my machine (Windows 10 64 bit, Anaconda 4.9.2, Java 1.8.0_281), I have encountered the following problem.
Running pyspark from the Powershell produces **no output** whatsoever, just a blank new line. The exact same thing happens if I run spark-shell.

I have downloaded different binary versions, but they all give me the exact same behaviour. I have checked the various SPARK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, etc. environment variables, and they all seem to be correctly set up.

Interestingly, I have the exact same behaviour with Scala binaries.

I also tried to pip install pyspark and create a spark context in Python, but I got the error

> Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its
> port number

As I mentioned, JAVA_HOME is correctly configured to point to my Java folder (which includes no space in the name...).

Has anyone ever incurred in such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to a spark and Java configuration, you think  it is well configured however it is not,  so please use the function below and change the spark and Java homes with yhiwr values in your work space. [image]

Comment: Hello there, I can see that spark is working, but I can also see that you are not on Windows 10 (hint: your folder paths gives it away somehow). As I mentioned, my problem is *already* at the Shell level. I had tried a similar solution that you suggest here, but to double check I implemented yours, putting particular care to point to the correct folders. It is not working, sorry.

Comment: I invite you to read my answer to this question , using windows and spark https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466236/writing-a-dataframe-in-parquet/66466655#66466655

Comment: Thanks, I have done this already. Trust me, I have scouted the internet a lot in search of an answer...

Comment: that's weird because it is a well known problem !!! well i do wish that ou can find an aswer to your prob'lm.