# Can't save to csv a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, pyspark

I have this spark dataframe that I use to filter in some information.

```py
df = spark_df.select(
    [
        "MENU",
        "NOM_SISTEMA",
        "DSC_GRP_USUARIO",
        "NOM_USUARIO",
        "NOM_FUNCIONARIO",
        "IND_ATIVO",
        "DAT_DESLIGAMENTO",
    ]
).where(
    (spark_df["MENU"].isNotNull())
    & (spark_df["IND_ATIVO"] == "S")
    & (spark_df["DAT_DESLIGAMENTO"].isNull())
)
```

After I obtain the output from the above operation, I tried to save the df to a csv file using

```
df.write.csv("C:/.../spark.csv")
```

but got the following error message:

> An error occurred while calling o85.csv.
> : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset**

Any suggestion to export my df to a csv or other format?

- Note: converting to pandas and then using `to_csv` isn't an option due to memory limitations.
- Note 2: I've been struggling to install hadoop on this machine since I don't own admin permissions
- Obs: Pyspark v3.2.0 and Python 3.9.7

Comment: Check this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66466655/14933870)

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue!

Comment: @GuillermoGarcia mark it as duplicate as it solved the issue.